# Rebase local branch ontop of github branch

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch "my_feature" that I've opened a pull request on Github for.

```
$ git branch my_feature
... made some changes
$ git add .
$ git push origin my_feature
```

Now another person made a change to the pull request, and I want to rebase my local branch on top of it. How do I do this?

I thought `git pull` would do this while im on `my_feature` branch, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` will rebase your work ontop of whatever the branch has configured as an upstream.  You can see this with `git branch -vv`.

If that isn't what you want to rebase against, they can set a new upstream and retry the rebase (`git branch --set-upstream-to=`) or you can do `git rebase --onto`